# Open the Keystore file in Java with password

Tags: java, security, keystore

I am trying to open a Password protected keystore file which I have it in the jre security Directory. I am using Bouncy Castel as my JCE. For some reason, I seem to get exceptions for which I have no clue as to why. Please help. Thanks. Here is what I have:

Code Snippet:

```
        String passwd = "abcd123";
        try {
            String file = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\security\\keystore.ssm";
            System.out.println("file =" + file);
            File keystoreFile = new File(file);
            if (keystoreFile.exists()) {
                KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC"); 
                //KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
                store.load(in, passwd.toCharArray());
                // Key key = store.getKey("mykeystore",passwd.toCharArray());
            }

        } catch (KeyStoreException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleBCTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(SimpleBCTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }  catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleBCTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } /*catch (UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(SimpleBCTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         } */ catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleBCTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (CertificateException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleBCTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Exception I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLSequence cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer